# How to get SmartArt information (text,name,type)from a slide?

Tags: c#, interop, powerpoint, openxml

I have to find following information from a smart art. 
**SmartArt type**,**SmartArt Name** and the **text** in it[image]

from the above image I want to find the below information

1. **type**: Hierarchy.
2. **name**: Organizational chart.
3. **text**: Madan4.

with or with out using interop
Till now by using OpenXML I can able to get only the text of a smart art.

```
var diagramDataPartsList = slidePart.DiagramDataParts;
if (diagramDataPartsList.Count() > 0)
{
    foreach (var diagramDataParts in diagramDataPartsList)
    {
        var text = diagramDataParts.DataModelRoot.PointList.InnerText;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(text.ToString());    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got my answer from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5c717ad2-bb7d-4382-98da-3affdb073c23/how-to-get-all-smartart-from-a-slide?forum=officegeneral&prof=required)
and the answer is

```
if (shape.HasSmartArt == MsoTriState.msoTrue)
{
    var val1 = shape.SmartArt;
    string name = val1.Layout.Name;
    string category = val1.Layout.Category;
    string text1 = "";
    foreach (SmartArtNode node in val1.AllNodes)
    {
        text1 += node.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Smartart : {0} \tCategory : {1}\t Name : {2} text : {3}", (i++).ToString(), category, name, text1);
}
```